# Single page scrolling nav items don't work on different page

Tags: jquery, scroll, nav, scrollto

I have built a wordpress theme that accommodates both a single page layout and separate pages (i.e. pages that navigate away from the front page). As with most single page layouts, you click on a nav item and it scrolls to that section. I have achieved this by giving the section an id and then putting that id in the menu link (i.e. #about or #contact).

This code then scrolls to the page section:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery('a[href*=#]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var navHeight = jQuery('#header').height();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var scrollTo = jQuery(id).offset().top-navHeight;

    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});

});
```

The problem I'm having, is when I navigate away from this page, and then click on a menu item that typically would scroll down the page - the menu items do not work.

I have tried using the full URL and also using '/#id' but neither of those options work. Is there a workaround I can use here?

Comment: Can you provide us a jsFiddle with one of your non-working example?

Comment: @DFayet not really as the issue happens when you navigate away to a different page on the site, and you can't replicate that in jsFiddle. You can look at the site itself if you like? http://thedistractionsband.skizzar.com scroll down to a singer and click to see an external link

Comment: When you are on a separate page and you click on the link you want to go back to the home and scroll down, or scroll down on the current page? Cause you won't be able to scroll down the current page as long as you don't have the corresponding element (the div). I know this questions may be stupid but I don't really understand your goal :/

Comment: @DFayet yeah I'd like to go back to the original page and scroll down - thats the plan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // The nav height can be set here if it will be always the same
    var navHeight = jQuery('#header').height();

    // Check if we have a hash (when we come back on the home)
    if( window.location.hash !== "" ) {

        var scrollTo = jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top-navHeight;

        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': scrollTo
        }, 500);

    }// if

    // Use your previous code if we're on the home page (thanks WP body_class() )
    jQuery('.home #nav a[href*=#]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var scrollTo = jQuery(id).offset().top-navHeight;

        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': scrollTo
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

It can contains some error, or you may need to do some little change but the general idea is here.

The main change is that we just check if we have a hash in the current url, and if it's the case we scroll on the element.

You need to change your menu's links with absolute url (or to /index.php#lorem) as your links are already customs it shouldn't impact you so much.

Hope it can helps you

*Remember that I didn't tested this code, so you can face some issues.*

Answer (score 0):

Here was the work around that I ended up using. 
The issue was that the code I was using was using the 'href' attribute as the ID for the section it should scroll to, this poses 2 problems:

1) When you navigate to a different page, if your URL is simply '#sectionID' then it won't work on the new page (unless there is a section with that ID - but you probably don't want the menu to scroll there even if there is)

2) If you try and use the full URL (i.e. http://yourwebsite.com/#sectionID) then the jquery code can't use that as the ID for the section it should scroll to.

The solution was pretty simple - get the code to look at a different attribute to take the section ID from - in this case I used the 'rel' attribute as that is built into wordpress menu options.

The new code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery('a[href*=#]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var navHeight = jQuery('#header').height();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    var scrollTo = jQuery('#' + id).offset().top-navHeight;

    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});

});
```

Now in the menu options I am using '/#sectionID' as the link and 'sectionID' as the link relationship.

Works like a charm.